# principles MVC understanding why

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

Im trying to understand the MVC pattern and i have some problems with it.
here is a example that works and is  a semi official MVC pattern.

```
class model {
    public $string;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->string = 'awsome MVC';
    }
}


class view {   
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller, $model){
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output(){
        return '<b>'.$this->model->string.'</b>';
    }
}


class controller {    
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}

$model = new Model();
$controller = new controller($model);
$view = new view($controller, $model);
echo $view->output();
```

i have problems with this, why is the view handling more then the controller?
below i have my own (i think) MVC script and i hope you guys can point out what im doing wrong and why the above example is better.

```
<?php 

/*
 * this is the view
 */
class template
{    
    function html($input){
        return 'template : <b>'.$input.'</b>';
    }
}

/*
 * this is the model
 */
class database 
{
    function output(){
        return 'this is a news title';
    }
}

/*
 * this is the basic controller
 */
class basicController 
{
    public $model;
    public $view;

    public function loadModel($model){
        $this->model = new $model;
    }

    public function loadView($view){
        $this->view = new $view;
    }
}

/*
 * this is the extended controller
 */
class newsController extends basicController 
{    
    public function __construct(){        
        $this->loadModel('database');
        $this->loadView('template');
    }

    public function showAction(){
        return $this->view->html($this->model->output());
    }
}

/*
 * calling
 */
$controller = new newsController;
echo $controller->showAction();

?>
```

Comment: Where exactly you found that *"semi official MVC pattern"*, because it's bullshit. View should not have access to controller.

Comment: http://r.je/mvc-in-php.html

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to learn MVC is to use an MVC framework. I did not fully understand it until I did that.

Comment: the links above is what i found on google, im trying to find a 'simple' example.

Comment: @Calum , no, that is the best way to *"feel like you are learning MVC"*. AFAIK, there are no PHP frameworks which implement MVC or something even slightly adhering to core ideas of MVC. They are ar just different variations on Rails.

Comment: @SinisterGlitch MVC as a pattern is not meant for "simple". You apply this pattern to large applications to add additional constraints, because simply adhering to best OOP practices is not enough anymore to contain the complexity of that particular codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and i know i cant start simple, yet i will try to be as 'core' as possible just to understand the principles. Can you all point out what i am doing wrong in my version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your definition of "semi-official MVC pattern" is wrong.

Here's the simplest "correct" MVC boilerplate I could come up with.

I know that understanding MVC principles can be hard sometimes but instead of writing your own mini-framework I would recommend looking into Laravel. It's a well documented and feature rich modern framework that could seem difficult to learn, but believe me, after you get the basics right you can't go wrong with it.

```
<?

/* 

Model represents a single entity. It doesn't have to be read or saved to the database. 
Example models: User, Post, Comment, Auction. 
Model class is used to operate on the model data, such as calculating the age of the user or calculating a comment count for a post.
*/
class Model {

    static function get($id) {
        return $obj; // Returns an object with given ID from the DB
    }

    static function all() {
        return $objc; // Returns all the objects.
    }

}

class User extends Model {
    public $name;
    public $surname;
}

/*

Controller handles the logic of the "app". It's used to load both the data and views and combine them together to serve output to the client.
Please keep in mind, that sometimes a controller can be used without the need of a model object (static pages) or view object (json output)

*/
class Controller {

    public function index() {
        $models = User::all();     
        $view = new View('index_view');
        $view->set('models', $models);

        return $view->render();
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $model = User::get($id);

        $view = new View('single_view');
        $view->set('model', $model);

        return $view->render();
    }

}

/*

View class is used to handle template loading and parsing. You can just include raw PHP files or create complex parsing rules

*/
class View {

    protected $file_name;
    protected $fields;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        $this->file_name = $filename;
    } 

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->fields[$key] = $value; // Store variable in the fields array
    }

    public function render() {
        extract($this->fields); // Make all the variables visible for the template file
        include($this->file_name); // Include the template file

        // You can add a buffer here to return the parsed template as a string. (see ob_flush() and ob_start())
    }

}

// single_view.php
<h1> Hello <?= $model->name ?></h1>

// index_view.php
<table>
    <? foreach($models as $model) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $model->name ?></td>
            <td><?= $model->surname ?></td> 
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you mate for this example, if i could upvote you i would do it(but i cant). I have seen 10+ different versions of MVC and this one is the clearest of all. I will implement your style and play with it untill it becomes intuitive.

Comment: Could you please explain what's wrong with Laravel's MVC pattern?

Comment: @tereško - then what it is?

Comment: @Darius.V mostly it's an adaptation of Rails-like architecture to PHP.